# Define TypeScript type that accepts object but not string

Tags: typescript

Short version:

I have an external type `ExternalFoo` that I can not modify.
I need to build type `Foo` which is equivalent to the `ExternalFoo` except that it should not accept `string`.

```
type ExternalFoo = {} | number | string;
type Foo = ???;
const foo1: Foo = {}; // ok
const foo1: Foo = 5; // ok
const foo2: Foo = "bar"; // not ok
```

Is it possible to define `Foo` based on the given `ExternalFoo` to satisfy this condition?

Longer version
I want to build a parametarized type that can accept any given `T` and return `T1` that is identical to `T` but doesn't allow for string.

I have a React app, and I want to force translation on it, we have a method `forceTranslation` method that accepts any React element, and changes specified properties such that they no longer accept `string` but can accept `TranslatedString`.

So if you have a component `<User firstName={"bob"}/>` the wrapped version (`const TranslatedUser = forceTranslation(User, ["bob"]);`) will compile-time fail if you give it `"bob"` but will succeed if you give it `translate("bob")`.

The issue is that `children` property of type `React.ReactNode` include `{}` in its definition. Using `Exclude<T, {}>` will also exclude `number` (among other things) from the type.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called "empty object type" `{}` is very wide; almost all values will be assignable to it.  Roughly, it will accept any value that can be indexed into *like* an object.  This includes all non-primitive types like [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), but it also includes the [five primitive types with wrapper objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript): so `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `bigint`, and `symbol` are assignable to `{}` because values of these types are  automatically wrapped in `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `BigInt`, and `Symbol` objects (respectively) when you access members on them as if they were objects.

In some sense this means your `ExternalFoo` type that cannot be changed is redundant: `{} | string | number` is basically equivalent to `{}` (but is both displayed differently and might be treated differently by the compiler in some circumstances).  I'm wondering if the actual intent of `ExternalFoo` was supposed to be more like `object | string | number` instead of `{} | string | number`.  Was it really meant to accept `boolean`, for example?

```
const wasThisIntended: ExternalFoo = true;
```

But you said you can't change it, so that's out of scope.

---

TypeScript does not have negated types (see [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)) so you cannot take `ExternalFoo` and quickly produce the version of it that rejects `string`.  Such a type like `ExternalFoo & not string` is simply not representable in TypeScript as it currently exists.  The [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) only filters unions.  And while `{} | number | string` can be filtered to produce either `{} | number`, `{}` itself cannot be filtered because it is not a union.

In order to exclude `string` from `ExternalFoo`, we would need not only to remove `string` from the definition, but change `{}` to something that also excludes `string`.  The type `{}` is more or less the same as `object | string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol`.  We can, if we want, remove `string` from *that*, to produce

```
type Foo = object | number | boolean | bigint | symbol;
```

So let's try that!

```
const foo1: Foo = {}; // okay
const foo2: Foo = 5; // okay
const foo3: Foo = "bar"; // error!
```

Looks good.  As desired, you can assign `{}` and `5` to a variable of type `Foo`, but you cannot assign `"bar"` to it.   This still happens:

```
const stillHappens: Foo = true; // okay
```

But `boolean` is not a `string` so I guess it's desired also.

---

For your longer version, I'd suggest trying to convert a generic type `T extends ExternalFoo` to `T & Foo` and see if it works for you:

```
type HasLength = { length: number };
let l: HasLength;
l = [1, 2, 3]; // okay 
l = "hello"; // okay
l = { length: 19 }; // okay

type NotString<T extends ExternalFoo> = T & Foo;

type HasLengthNotString = NotString<{ length: number }>;
let n: HasLengthNotString;
n = [1, 2, 3]; // okay
n = "hello"; // error
n = { length: 19 }; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-02zhc9QOxTtgB7LheDGVD0L7TdtzA3dqHoXUYIhD8IEkFAz15C8COw3teEEE0iFve9HxfOCE2YjZv1-f9oWQQsBG4vDkMIqCYNfeCBCAA)

Comment: I'm working with React. The `ExternalFoo` in this case is `ReactNode` which [includes](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3423b4fc3e3da09f8acc386bc2fee6fb8f5e0880/types/react/index.d.ts#L232-L233) `{}` through `ReactFragment`

Comment: I have also attempted to handle `{}` exclusion explicitly, i.e. do something like: `object extends ExternalFoo ? Exclude<ExternalFoo, {} |string> | object | TranslatedString` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Exclude` utility.

```
type ExternalFoo = number | string;
type Foo = Exclude<ExternalFoo, string>;

const a: Foo = "hi"; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

All built-in utilities in TypeScript:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: But you modified `ExternalFoo` from `{} | number | string` to `number | string`.

Comment: Yes @jcalz. Using `{}` is a bad practice, so I omitted it. As stated by `TypeScript` itself:
Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".
- If you want a type meaning "any object", you probably want `Record<string, unknown>` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "any value", you probably want `unknown` instead.
- If you want a type meaning "empty object", you probably want `Record<string, never>` instead.

You are right @jcalz. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the context of my comment: the question says "I have an external type `ExternalFoo` that I cannot modify", so modifying `ExternalFoo`, no matter how nice it would be to do so, seems to be out of scope for the question.  I agree that `{}` is probably not what anyone wants.

Comment: As pointed out by @jcalz. This side-steps my problem. Downvoting to reflect that.

Comment: Yes @jcalz. I understood. I just tried to point out the usage of `Exclude`. Thanks